# Swift FCM: Sending Push Notifications when Database receives updates

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I hope this post does not get marked down as I genuinely am unable to find a good starting point.

I am looking for a solution to send push notifications to users when there is an update to FIRDatabase. Just imagine building a chat app, which users receive a notification when they receive a new message. I attempted with Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), but I could not get any further past sending notifications from Firebase Console manually like so in the following tutorials:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBw5tuTvKd4&t=679s

I have spent nearly 2 hours searching for more tutorials on youtube and everywhere else but this area seems scarce.

Can anyone advice any tutorial that I can begin with, or is my approach even correct in the first place.

Comment: Look into the recently released Cloud Functions for Firebase.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/  There is sample code that triggers FCM when the database changes.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Comment: @Koh how can i achieve this in the ios Swift app? I want to send notifications to all registered users whenever a new product is added to my realtime Firebase Database. How is that possible?

Comment: @MahrukhRaza you might wanna check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871379/firebase-cloudfunctions-querying-nodes/42876008#42876008

Comment: @Koh thanks for pointing that out. But this uses javascript. How can i write javascript in xcode? And how will it run if i upload something to app store?

Comment: @MahrukhRaza I doubt we can write javascript in xcode. Basically the notifications portion from firebase is done on server side (the backend), thats why in node.js. Firebase listens for write events to the relevant database nodes, and then push a notification to the phone. Alternatively you can try OneSignal that also handles notifications, but im not sure if it can be integrated with firebase

Comment: I too want to achieve this functionality. I've achieved sending and receiving notification using cloud function in android but I do not know how to receive the notification in iOS (xcode-swift). Could anybody please help me as to how to receive notification sent via cloud function to a device using its device token in xcode swift?

Comment: @Arjun does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876008/6792327

Comment: Thanks Koh. Helped me :)